# How does StackWalker.Option SHOW_HIDDEN_FRAMES work in Java 9

Tags: java, java-9

I've been exploring the StackWalking API introduced in jdk9. I couldn't see any difference in the output with or without the option `StackWalker.Option.SHOW_HIDDEN_FRAMES`.

As per the [API documentation](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/index.html):

> A Java Virtual Machine implementation may hide implementation specific
>   frames in addition to reflection frames. A StackWalker with this
>   SHOW_HIDDEN_FRAMES option will show all hidden frames (including
>   reflection frames)

Can anyone please help me understand which exact frames could the JVM hide in addition to the reflection frames? What is the exact use of this option?

This is my demo code:

```
class DemoClass {

    public static void a() {
        b();
    }

    static void b() {
        c();
    }

    static void c() {
        d();
    }

    static void d() {
        StackWalker sw = StackWalker.getInstance(Set.of(StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE, StackWalker.Option.SHOW_HIDDEN_FRAMES));
        sw.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

public class StackWalkerAPI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Method methodA = Class.forName("DemoClass").getMethod("a");
            methodA.invoke(null, (Object[]) null);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StackWalkerAPI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what did you meant by *not working in Java 9*. Here, using [this sample code](https://github.com/namannigam/Jigsaw/blob/master/internal/src/experiment/StackWalkerDemo.java), to explain in details the output of a similar code as yours:

> [`StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/StackWalker.Option.html#RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE) displays the Class object in StackFrames walked by this StackWalker.

```
internal/experiment.StackWalkerDemo.lambda$d$0(StackWalkerDemo.java:29)
java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
internal/experiment.StackWalkerDemo.d(StackWalkerDemo.java:28)
internal/experiment.StackWalkerDemo.c(StackWalkerDemo.java:20)
internal/experiment.StackWalkerDemo.b(StackWalkerDemo.java:16)
internal/experiment.StackWalkerDemo.a(StackWalkerDemo.java:12)
internal/experiment.StackWalkerAPI.main(StackWalkerAPI.java:15)
```

---

> [`StackWalker.Option.SHOW_REFLECT_FRAMES`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/StackWalker.Option.html#SHOW_REFLECT_FRAMES)
>   Shows all reflection frames

```
internal/experiment.StackWalkerDemo.lambda$d$0(StackWalkerDemo.java:29)
java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
internal/experiment.StackWalkerDemo.d(StackWalkerDemo.java:28)
internal/experiment.StackWalkerDemo.c(StackWalkerDemo.java:20)
internal/experiment.StackWalkerDemo.b(StackWalkerDemo.java:16)
internal/experiment.StackWalkerDemo.a(StackWalkerDemo.java:12)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
internal/experiment.StackWalkerAPI.main(StackWalkerAPI.java:15)
```

Notice the statement **`java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)`** here, as mentioned in the docs as well this option shows all reflection frames including `Method.invoke(o1,o2)` and `Constructor.newInstance(o)`.

---

> [`StackWalker.Option.SHOW_HIDDEN_FRAMES`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/StackWalker.Option.html#SHOW_HIDDEN_FRAMES)
>   Shows all hidden frames.

```
internal/experiment.StackWalkerDemo.lambda$d$0(StackWalkerDemo.java:29)
internal/experiment.StackWalkerDemo$$Lambda$23/1358444045.accept(Unknown Source)
java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
internal/experiment.StackWalkerDemo.d(StackWalkerDemo.java:28)
internal/experiment.StackWalkerDemo.c(StackWalkerDemo.java:20)
internal/experiment.StackWalkerDemo.b(StackWalkerDemo.java:16)
internal/experiment.StackWalkerDemo.a(StackWalkerDemo.java:12)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
internal/experiment.StackWalkerAPI.main(StackWalkerAPI.java:15)
```

Look for **`internal/experiment.StackWalkerDemo$$Lambda$23/1358444045.accept(Unknown Source)`** which is a frame for performing the operation on the lambda(*implementation specific frames*) and is accessible using this option.

Comment: This is what I had been looking for. In my program I'd been observing the same output for Option.SHOW_REFLECT_FRAMES & Option.SHOW_HIDDEN_FRAMES. I tried few other examples as well, but couldn't find a use case where the output using SHOW_HIDDEN_FRAMES is different.

Are you aware of any other use case?

Comment: @VikramSherigar There is a [github sample code](https://github.com/namannigam/Jigsaw/blob/master/internal/src/experiment/StackWalkerDemo.java) already linked in the answer which reflects this difference in the output. Hope that helps. :)